# Can't login Form Recognizer Studio(Preview)

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

I am trying Form Recognizer Studio(Preview), when I click Custom Models, it popup screen below

[image]
After login with my .hotmail account, it throw

[image]

Comment: It appears you need to get additional permissions - contact your administrator?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss What do you mean by administrator? i am using personal email microsoft account which has azure subscription.

Comment: Check the permissions for the Cognitive Service in the Azure portal?